# Is there a native method in nestjs to decode JWT?

Tags: jwt, nestjs, nestjs-passport, nestjs-jwt

In nestjs I create JWT (tokens) by creating a payload object and signing it. Something like this:

```
    const jwtPayload: JwtPayload = 
    {
      iss:                issuer,
      sub:                info,
      aud:                audience,
   // exp:                - populated by fn: this.jwtService.sign(payload),
   // iat:                - populated by fn: this.jwtService.sign(payload),
      jti:                'XXXX1234' 
    }

const signedJwtAccessToken: string = this.jwtService.sign(jwtPayload);
```

Nest encodes the jwtPayload into a string.

For cleanup work I would like to know when exactly the JWT expires. This is automatically encoded into the '*signedJwtAccessToken*' - property *.exp* - by the .sign() function.

To access it right after the signing, it needs to be decoded.

What would be the simplest way to decode the *signedJwtAccessToken* in the same method right after it has been signed ???

Note:

When the JWT comes back from client, nestjs decodes it when accessing the fn: validate(), but I want to decode right after signing it - before sending the response to client, something like:

```
                            // signing - encoding
const signedJwtAccessToken: string = this.jwtService.sign(jwtPayload);

                            // decoding
const decodedJwtAccessToken: string = decodeJwt(signedJwtAccessToken);

                            // parsing back to an object
const updatedJwtPayload: JwtPayload  = JSON.parse(decodedJwtAccessToken);

                            // reading property of .exp
const expires = updatedJwtPayload.exp;
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just decode it as a normal jwt token. If you use [nestjs-jwt](https://github.com/nestjs/jwt) package, just call [decode](https://github.com/nestjs/jwt#jwtservicedecodetoken-string-options-decodeoptions-object--string) function:

```
const decodedJwtAccessToken: JwtPayload = this.jwtService.decode(signedJwtAccessToken);

const expires = decodedJwtAccessToken.exp;
```

Or just decode the token as a base64 string

```
const base64Payload = signedJwtAccessToken.split('.')[1];
const payloadBuffer = Buffer.from(base64Payload, 'base64');
const updatedJwtPayload: JwtPayload = JSON.parse(payloadBuffer.toString()) as JwtPayload;
const expires = updatedJwtPayload.exp;
```

Comment: Obviously, it was just staring into my face. Thanks for the reminder. Just a slight adjustment for TS to be happy:
     const decodedJwtAccessToken: JwtPayload = this.jwtService.decode(signedJwtAccessToken) as JwtPayload;

Answer (score 1):

if don't want to inject jwtService you can use this way:

```
import { decode } from 'jsonwebtoken';

const jwtPayload = decode(yourJwtToken);
```

> jsonwebtoken [npm lib docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken)